# Rate/VotingAPI - Add class to button if user has voted

Tags: 7, rating

I want to add a class to a button after the user has voted to display another picture.

This was posted [here](http://drupal.org/node/938366#comment-3561418) as a solution for Drupal 6.

```
<?php
  // Print all rate buttons
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    if ($results['user_vote'] == $link['value']) {
      // user has voted
      $class = 'voted';
    }
    else {
      // user has not voted
      $class = 'not-voted';
    }
    print theme('rate_button', $link['text'], $link['href'], $class);
  }
?>
```

I couldn't get it to work, so I assumed that I had to convert it to D7 first. However, I have no skills of converting code, so a little help would be nice.

Comment: which widget type are you using at the moment?

Comment: @Aboodred1 I'm using the "Thumbs up" widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change will only work for "Thumbs up" widget. You can place this code in your template.php under your custom theme or in a custom module.

```
function MODULE_NAME_OR_TEMPLATE_NAME_process_rate_template_thumbs_up(&$variables) {
  extract($variables);

  $classes = 'rate-thumbs-up-btn-up';

  if (isset($results['user_vote']) && $results['user_vote'] == $links[0]['value']) {
    $classes .= ' user-voted';
  } else {
    $classes .= ' user-not-voted';
  }

  $variables['up_button'] = theme('rate_button', array('text' => $links[0]['text'], 'href' => $links[0]['href'], 'class' => $classes));
}
```

Make sure to replace `MODULE_NAME_OR_TEMPLATE_NAME` with an actual template name or module name.

Comment: The problem there is, if your page content is cached, you won't get the current user's vote state, instead the vote state of the user when the content was cached.

Comment: Are you sure about that @DavidThomas? Have you tried it with and without page cache?

Comment: Well, obviously a template tweak to set the HTML output can potentially be cached. However, if you're relying on regular Drupal page cache, it won't be active for authenticated users. Other caching methods for authenticated users will cache that user vote state from the HTML markup though.

Comment: Well, I tried it with regular Drupal page cache using authenticated and anonymous user and it worked both ways.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, default page cache is inactive for authenticated users so it won't be cached..

Comment: So is there a solution to cache it?

Comment: To bypass cache, you would need to do an ajax callback to get the vote state for that page, then apply it to the vote widget(s).

Comment: @DavidThomas Will this code only work after you've refreshed the page? I would like it to add the class immediately after you click the button.

Comment: @Alexandberg this code will work after you refresh the page and after clicking the button because its an ajax call.

Comment: @Aboodred1 Great. I will try it soon.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)